# Is there a way to get data other than HTTP?

Tags: ajax, selenium, titanium

I'm using Selenium and Titanium Web Proxy to capture some data from a website.

I create an instance of `IWebDriver`, setup proxy, load the URL and wait for it to be fully loaded, then I start clicking on one specific element.
Once clicked, that element triggers an AJAX call that updates data on the page, including the element itself. Then I wait for a second, find that element, and click it again, and so on.

Everything works and I can see the AJAX calls being made, in `Network` tab, and I also log URLs in `BeforeResponse` event handler of the proxy.

However, after a while, there is no AJAX calls, while the data on the page gets updated and links get clicked. I can see that data is updated, but I can't see any AJAX call being made in `Network` tab anymore.

How is it possible? What are the possible technologies that I don't know? Or maybe this is a simple bug of Selenium and Titanium together?

Comment: Data transfer to client can be  either http, gRpc, websocket connections, other than http may be the other two

Comment: How can I see gRpc or other transfer mechanisms logs in Google Chrome?

Comment: So I believe polifil.js kind of things will helps